# How to select one row if condition true, other row if condition false in sql?

Tags: sql

So there could be two rows for each proposal, one row where bt.stage_id = 1 if it is accepted, but not reconciled, and 1 row for stage 2.

I want to perform the following calculation, but only add the stage 2 not the stage 1 if the stage 2 is present, how do I do this?

```
SELECT SUM(bt.novartis_total) AS 'NovartisTotal' 
FROM budget_totals bt, rfp_proposal rp 
WHERE (bt.rfp_proposal_id = 1 OR bt.rfp_proposal_id = 22) 
    AND rp.status_type='Accepted' 
    AND rp.vendor_id=2 
    AND (rp.id = 1 OR rp.id=22)
```

So here is some sample data:
row 1

rp.id = 22, stage_id = 2, novartis_total = 3750

row 2

rp.id = 22, stage_id = 1, novartis_total = 40000

row 3

rp.id = 11, stage_id = 2, novartis_total = 7580

row 4

rp.id = 11, stage_id = 1, novartis_total = 20000

row 5

rp.id = 24, stage_id = 1, novartis_total = 8591

row 6

rp.id = 1, stage_id = 1, novartis_total = 6092

The sum should be of novartis totals and disregard the 20k and 40k values for id's 22 and 11 in the stage 1 rows.

Comment: use a case statement in the sum...

Comment: It might help if you provide a small amount of test data, as well as the output you expect to get.

Comment: the actual stage 1 rp 11 and 22 values are the same as the stage 2 values, but this illustrates the point.

Comment: You said the total should be 26013, but I don't understand on what basis you disregard the 40000 and 20000.

Comment: For example, 8591 is on a row where rp.id = 24, but your query doesn't see this row.

Comment: Disregard the 40k and 20k because there is a row for that id with a stage_id = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE bt.stage_id
             WHEN 2 THEN bt.novartis_total
             ELSE 0
           END) AS 'NovartisTotal'
FROM   budget_totals bt,
       rfp_proposal rp
WHERE  ( bt.rfp_proposal_id = 1
          OR bt.rfp_proposal_id = 22 )
       AND rp.status_type = 'Accepted'
       AND rp.vendor_id = 2
       AND ( rp.id = 1
              OR rp.id = 22 )
```

Comment: I don't think that takes into account adding the stage_id 1 value if stage_id 2 isn't present.

Answer (score 2):

The query you posted lacks JOIN criteria, making a cartesian product -- use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.stage_id = 1 THEN bt.novartis_total 
             ELSE 0 
           END) - SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.stage_id = 2 THEN bt.novartis_total 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS 'NovartisTotal_stage1',
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN bt.stage_id = 2 THEN bt.novartis_total 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS 'NovartisTotal_stage2'
  FROM BUDGET_TOTALS bt
  JOIN RFP_PROPOSAL rp ON rp.id = bt.rfp_proposal_id 
 WHERE bt.rfp_proposal_id IN (1, 22) 
   AND rp.status_type = 'Accepted' 
   AND rp.vendor_id = 2
```

Only need to subtract the number of stage 2 records from the stage 1... unless you have data issues where someone can be stage 2 without having ever been stage 1.

Comment: I think that is close, but I want an output with 1 row, 1 column that contains a total value of bt_novartis_total from stage 2, not stage 1 if stage 2 is present, so it should sum stage 2 and 1 values only if there are different bt_rfp_proposal_id's if one of those id's has a stage two and one only has a stage one

Comment: @mprotoype: Update your question to include sample data and expected output based on the data.  I'm not interesting in helping you further until that happens - Jeffrey Kemp deserves a medal for helping you get this far.

Comment: All I needed to do was combine the two statements into one total!

Comment: Actually numbers don't add up

Comment: Out put on sample data for this result = 13672 should be 26013.

Comment: @mprototype: no, from the conditions stated, the result should be 9,842 - ie. novartis_total for rows 1 and 6 only. Rows 3, 4 and 5 should be excluded because their rp.id values are neither 1 nor 22, while row 2 should be excluded because it is stage_id 1 for an rp.id where stage 2 exists (ie. row 1). If there are additional requirements that would cause a different expected total from the same sample data, please can you add them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` + subqueries are your friend. I couldn't work out what you mean by "stage 1" or "stage 2", but here is the gist of how you can do it:

```
SELECT (query for stage 1)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (query for stage 2)
UNION ALL
SELECT (query for stage 2)
;
```

Comment: how does that help? where is the SUM?

Comment: So:SELECT (
SUM(bt.novartis_total) AS 'NovartisTotal' 
  
     FROM budget_totals bt, rfp_proposal rp 
     
     WHERE (bt.rfp_proposal_id = 1 OR bt.rfp_proposal_id = 22) AND bt.stage_id=2 AND  rp.status_type='Accepted' AND rp.vendor_id=2 AND (rp.id = 1 OR rp.id=22)
)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SUM(bt.novartis_total) AS 'NovartisTotal' 
  
     FROM budget_totals bt, rfp_proposal rp 
     
     WHERE (bt.rfp_proposal_id = 1 OR bt.rfp_proposal_id = 22) AND bt.stage_id=1 AND  rp.status_type='Accepted' AND rp.vendor_id=2 AND (rp.id = 1 OR rp.id=22)
)
UNION ALL

Comment: I need to get one sum row as the result query

Comment: @mprototype: that's because you have nothing after the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You said "one row where bt.stage_id = 1 if it is accepted, but not reconciled, AND 1 row for stage 2" so I assumed you wanted two rows.

Comment: @Mitch: the SUM is in the "(query for stage n)" in my response.

Comment: Need one row that counts the total by adding the total if a row is present with a 2 in the stage_id field or the total from the row with stage_id field value = 1 if no stage_id=2 row is present.

Comment: @mprototype: if you actually only want *one* row, but with multiple *columns*, then OMG Ponies has your answer.

Comment: where the rp.id value is given at query time.

Comment: 1 row, 1 column. Output should be the sum of totals, but take into account whether or not a row with the stage_id value = 2 is present and disregard the row with stage_id = 1 where the rp.id is set if the stage 2 is present.

Comment: The error was actually from the first line of the first query... I did try with the second query after union all.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I don't want to add the stage 1 and stage 2 counts. I want to add to the total only the stage 2 value if stage 2 is present and in that case disregard the value for the row that stage = 1 else add the value for the row where stage = 1

Comment: @mprototype: See update - only need to subtract the number of stage 2 records from the stage 1... unless you have data issues where someone can be stage 2 without having ever been stage 1.